# How to generate JWKSource<SecurityContext>?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I tried to use a semantic key to generate `JWKSet` to be using during encoded process.

I have a secret key and I create an object from `OctetSequenceKey`, see below code:

```java
public static OctetSequenceKey generateHSKey(SecretKey key) {

    return new OctetSequenceKey.Builder(key)
                       .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
                           .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) 
                           .algorithm(JWSAlgorithm.HS256).build();                                                                                                                                               
}
```

and then I tried to create `JWKSet` with below code:

```java
@Bean
public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        JWKSet jwkSet1 = new JWKSet(hsKey()); // calling generateHSKey()
        System.out.println(jwkSet1.toJSONObject()); // {keys:[]}

        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
}
```

`{keys:[]}` in `JWKSet` is always `null`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by *semantic key* you actually mean *symmetric key*, which is a "shared" **PRIVATE** key used to both encrypt & decrypt data, as opposed to a private/public key pair used in asymmetric encryption, where one key is used to encrypt and the other to decrypt, or, well "sign" in this context (a bit more detailed explanation/example [here](https://medium.com/@swayamraina/symmetric-vs-asymmetric-jwts-bd5d1a9567f6)).

With this in mind, if you take a look at the [javadoc of the JWKSet.toJsonObject() method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/latest/com/nimbusds/jose/jwk/JWKSet.html#toJSONObject()), it reads:

[image: toJsonObject() javadoc]

Since this is a private key, you want to use `.toJsonObject(false)` to include all keys in the result, but other than that I don't believe there's anything to fix and your app should work normally. Furthermore, if you're building an auth server, please be aware that since the key is private it will also not be listed if you access the `jwks_uri`, eg: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/jwks

---

**Alternative way to create a `JWKSource` using a secret**

I had a similar requirement, and I had a secret defined as in my `application.yaml` which then was bound as a `String` to a POJO (eg: `settings.getJwt().getSecret()`). Overall my implementation looks like this:

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableSecret;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


@Bean
public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
    return new ImmutableSecret<>(new SecretKeySpec(settings.getJwt().getSecret().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "MHmacSHA256"));
}
```